# How to reduce size of LinearLayout with Background Image large one

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I am trying to draw 2 layouts vertically with top one containing image,Since Image is very big,it is occupying some portion of botton half,I used weights =1 and layoutheight=0dp to partition it equally,

Without any Image,Partition is perfect,But if i set background Image to toplayout ,Weight ratio is not perfect,which is of no reuse,

I tried using framelayout,which is also of no use,

What is exact way of doing it in xml,instead of assiging layouts height programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">
   </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then you can set the image as a background for the top layout.

Comment: Add to your main Layout `android:weightSum="1"`

Comment: @ArturSzymański Thanks for your comment.

Comment: This does not work,When  you set the image set for layout is larger,Weight is not getting affected.

Comment: @Rakesh on which layout you are applying your background image?

Comment: @Rakesh No matter how the image is large, it shouldn't exceed the layout space. Maybe you missed something, can you post yor code?

Comment: Hi Guys,Finally understood the root of issue,it is not due to image,but due to coverflow which i was adding to the second half of linearlayout,But it is working perfectly during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give your views relative space ,here is new android library which you may want to try.

### Percent Support Library

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#percent

and you can use it in your project like:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="100%" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="100%" />

    </android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```